# CentOS 5.6: Setup global extensions in Firefox 10.0.1

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, administration, centos-5

I have setup Firefox to run off a server for a group of people, so that it runs for them without a local install. Now, I wish to also setup a few extensions globally, which would be available to all users by default - would be great if I could also configure them!

Some desired addons as of now - Firebug, downloadHelper, new tab redirect

Answer (score 0):

Manually download the extension, and then install by running the Firefox binary with the `-install-global-extension` switch with an argument that is the pathname to the extension.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments

Comment: I tried it, but the extensions still only got installed locally to my profile & were not available to everyone :(